# intel xdk cordova locally plugin not working

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I new to intel xdk from jboss developer and in jboss we can put all the plugin in plugins folder and check with the plugins option to included everything.

But in intel xdk I found the way to include plugins is not the same and also dunno its working or not till I build the apk and test with the phone.

What I do with intel xdk is I move the plugins folder into www folder and then use the plugin local option to one by one added.

This is all the step I do, please let me know what I need to do to complete the plugins for my app.

Because I used cmd cordova build with debug apk have no problem.

Buy intel xdk is something new to me.

Please give me tutorial from step 1 to end.
I search the intel xdk website and other website but no one really do the tutorial or fully explain on this.

Moat of them are talk about the CLI cordova plugin and even said about the local plugin, is add with the folder inside your project folder that all.

From here I don't know how yo continue if there is any other step I miss out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article online at https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/adding-third-party-plugins-to-your-xdk-cordova-app that goes into detail about including local plugins to your app.   In the projects tab, you can manage third party plugins.  You will add the reference to the plugin there.

> References to your third-party plugins, whether imported from a local directory or a public repo, are listed in the "Third-Party Plugins" section of the Projects tab (see the image below for an example). The Name field you specified above is arbitrary and is used strictly as an identifier here and in the build message log. The Plugin ID must match that specified inside the plugin.xml file (see the registry or the plugin's git repo). At this time there is no way to edit or inspect the data you provided during the plugin import process; if you need to change the Name or Plugin ID or other fields you must delete the plugin reference (click the (X) icon) and re-import the plugin with the revised Name, Plugin ID and other fields.